# Shell operators non-zero (-n) and zero length (-z) both return True for the same variable!!! Inconceivable

Tags: bash, sh

Why does the non-zero and the zero operator both return true in the shell script? This makes no sense. 
Please see the following small script I have written. I set a variable 'zero' to have nothing. I also get the same results if I set 'zero' to "" or `zero=""`.

```
zero=

#the below code prints - "is not length zero"
if [ -n $zero ] ; 
then      
 echo "$zero is not length zero" ; 
fi

#the below code prints - " is length 0" 
if [ -z $zero ] ; then     echo "$zero is length 0";  fi
```

Thank-you for reading this. Please make fun of me until I loose all sense of reality.

Regards,

Comment: Quote your variables in `[...]`, e.g. `if [ -z "$zero" ]` (Ye have been warned...) What you are doing is `[ -n ] && echo "true"` and `[ -z ] && echo "true"`

Comment: If you are using bash and you are highly reluctant to quoting, you can use the double braces: `[[ -n $zero ]]` and `[[ -z $zero ]]`. This will not be portable to an other shell.

Comment: Warning: double-quotes are sometimes significant even inside `[[ ]]` -- for example, `[[ $var1 = $var2 ]]` will treat the content of `var2` as a glob (wildcard) pattern, while `[[ $var1 = "$var2" ]]` will treat it as a literal string. IMO it's better to just get in the habit of double-quoting variable references in the shell than to try to keep track of when it's safe to leave them off.

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems in your shell code.  In this case it warns about missing quotes.

Answer (score 2):

### Quote variables when used with comparison operators within test brackets

Its always best practice, because of string splitting, to quote variables in case the variable contains a space.

In the case of comparison operators, it will lead to failure if you don't.

The [LDP docs](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for the n operator actually state '***The -n test requires that the string be quoted within test brackets.***'

Here's an updated version of the code that works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


zero= # Zero-length ("null") string variable.

#the below code prints $zero is null.

echo "Test for zero length using -n comparison operator"
if [ -n "$zero" ] ; # if string is not null
then
 echo "\$zero is not null" ;
else
echo "\$zero is null"
fi

echo "Test for zero length using -z comparison operator"
#the below code prints $zero is null.


if [ -z "$zero" ]
then
  echo "\$zero is null."
else
  echo "\$zero is NOT null."
fi
```

> operator reference

- The -n comparison operator checks if a string is not null
- The -z comparison operator does the opposite, returning true if the string is null, that is, has zero length.
- [LDP - 7.3 Other comparison operators](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)